# sql server 2008 treat n and ñ as equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to treat `n` and `ñ` as equal?

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(50) = 'naño'

SELECT * FROM Table1 A WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @NAME + '%'
```

The table contains nano and naño

Case 1: @NAME = 'nano' return nano and naño

Case 2: @NAME = 'naño' return nano and naño

Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Specify another collation for Name column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try changing the collation for your 'like' clause.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE [Name] LIKE '%' + @NAME + '%' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

where the "AI" stands for "Accent Insensitive"

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to declare the column to have that collation? (With consistent table design, you rarely never have to do `collate` in your queries.)

Comment: @jarlh Agreed but we don't always get to decide